# Add Low Pass Filter to existing Stereo Amp Circuit

Tags: audio, filter

[image]

I have designed a simple stereo amplifier which is attached below, but the bass output was bit poor. So I'm planning to add extra low pass filter circuit to this circuit. I don't have any idea how to do that properly.
My requirement is to have separate left and right channels and an extra woofer out.

Comment: What do You mean by "base output is poor"? Look at Fig 10 in BA5406 datasheet - at low frequencies gain of that IC is dramatic, You should find something better, like TDA2009.

Comment: Probably means 'bass' output is poor.

Comment: What do you mean by 'poor'? Do you mean that the lower frequencies are not loud enough?

Comment: Addng a low pass filter won't improve anything. It will *reduce* the upper frequencies. That's no way to improve the perceived bass response. The problem here is the 470uF coupling capacitors into a 4 ohm load: that's a *high*-pass filter with -3dB at 84.66Hz. Try 4700uF, or even 10,000uF.

Comment: Sorry to tell you that the above diagram is for example.. the point is I want to build extra subwoofer box and a low pass filter circuit for my existing stereo amplifier.

Comment: P.s in brief.. I wanna alt my stereo amplifier to 2.1 amplifier.

Comment: The specs of your woofer would be nice to have, input impedance in particular. Also you'd probably need a separate IC to add gain from the input  to the woofer.

Comment: @RanathCS: 'the point is I want to build extra subwoofer box and a low pass filter circuit for my existing stereo amplifier.' Well why didn't you ask that. -1.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide a link to the chip datasheet, we don't know what it's supposed to do.

However, without knowing anything about the chip, it is obvious that really low bass performance will be poor.  470 µF in series with a 4 Ω speaker forms a high pass filter.  In this case, the rolloff frequency is 85 Hz, or 2 octaves above what is considered the lowest "HiFi" audio frequency.  Larger caps or a higher impedance speakers would lower the high pass filter rolloff frequency.